# Efficient transfer protocol for mobile equipment

Tags: python, optimization, mobile, network-protocols

I am working on a platform having a GPRS data connection. What I have now is a custom protocol over TCP or UDP which I'm thinking to change. The device in the current state sends small chunks of data periodically (let's say 30seconds or 5 minutes - this can, and probably will, change). My concern is that the data being sent will start to be more and more complex over the time. What I want:

- a protocol that has a good balance (as good as possible) between information sent and size of data sent (GPRS costs money so data sent must have as little size as possible)
- a protocol that is easily extensible when packet information changes

For now my solutions are:

1. a custom protocol  (which I'm using now)
2. a standard/open protocol (I've heard about binary xml but haven't found something clear).

Constraints:

- the device has little computational power so compressing data is out of the question, except for less cpu intensive methods like [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).
- the language used is python with **a lot** of features turned off (imagine a stripped python implementation containing only lists, dictionaries, some basic string operations, Exceptions, sys module with little functionality, tuples and other custom (non-standard) functions).

Given these constraints what is a good/best method for transmitting data over the network? (I'm referring to the protocol used above TCP/UDP)

Any information/hints/experiences/implementations are helpful.

Thanks,

Iulian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your constraints, properly encoded JSON sounds reasonable.

- It is fairly light-weight (size of data + quotes and {})
- It is extensible. You don't need to decide on a fixed format up front. Adding keys is trivial for both the transmission and receiving.
- You can use `eval()` to get a Python dictionary (since your version of Python is stripped down). You can also use [simplejson](https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson) in Python 2.5+ without any dependencies.
- It is a common format for data exchange across other languages (JavaScript, etc)

Comment: Good to know. I will take it into consideration. Right now I'm analyzing the development of a binary xml format, which is basically the same thing as XML/JSON but binary encoded with IDs instead of tags and the content of each ID has a size parameter/maybe even a CRC. Anyway it's good to know that people tend to use protocols that resemble xml/object format.

Comment: This answer is the closest to what I'm implementing now. Because there are no other answers I will chose this one as the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Given this constraints what is a good
>   (the best) method for transmitting
>   data over the network?

No idea what that shall mean but you should be able to open a UDP or TCP connection using
Python and transmit your data as needed...what is the real question?

Comment: I edited the question. I'm talking about the protocol used to encode data, data that will be sent on tcp/udp channel)